mysql hangs on dkpg upgrade
Today I ran an upgrade to 24.04 and towards the end of the upgrade it appears MySQL went into running mode and the upgrade never passed mysqld is running as pid X. So I rebooted and fortunately it all came back up but when running an apt-get upgrade was advised:
root@user-Inspiron-16-7610:/home/user# apt-get upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
root@user-Inspiron-16-7610:/home/user# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.36-2ubuntu3) ...
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 5244

And yet again it just hangs. Maybe I'm being impatient but it just feels like its in console mode and isn't going to complete. I'm also not sure if any other packages didn't complete their upgrade so I'd really like dpkg to complete.
How can I resolve this console hanging? Now having restarted, an apt-get upgrade recognises the failed install but equally hangs?

It turns out that in the /var/log/mysql/error.log was an error because I was running mysql with skip-grant-tables on. As such the upgrade couldn't run. Removing that fixed it and allowed dkpg to continue as expected.
